# Changing the time of an already changed Outlook recurring appointment occurrence does not save the change using Redemption

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

The problem I'm facing here is simplest described as the following steps:

1. Create a recurring appointment in Outlook by hand
2. Change the time of one of the occurrences by hand
3. Now in any test program, use Redemption to find the master Outlook appointment, then access to it's recurrence pattern then get the changed occurrence from the exceptions list
4. Change the time of this particular occurrence and save it by calling its `RDOAppointmentItem.Save` method
5. Repeat step 3 to get the same occurrence, the time in this occurrence is the old time before step 4

I have tried starting a new thread to perform step 5 hoping that Outlook could have a chance to save the change into MAPI table but I got the same incorrect time.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: So the problem is that Outlook does not see the change? Or that the change does not persist even after you restart Outlook?

Comment: Outlook does not see the change. After saving the changed occurrence programmatically, I didn't see the particular occurrence changes in Outlook, and the appointment item captured from the item changed event still has the old start time.

Comment: Do yo use the change after restarting Outlook?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "use the change" but the occurrence stays the same after restarting Outlook. I've also tested this by programmatically getting an unchanged occurrence, changed its start time, saved it and saw the change reflected in Outlook, then got the same occurrence again, changed the start time and saved again, but this time Outlook didn't see the change.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "do you see.." - autocorrect is not playing nicely :-) Or are you saying the recurrence blob does not get updated correctly after the second change?  Take a look at the appointment in OutlookSpy - click IMessage button when the appointment is selected in the Calendar view, select the AppointmentRecur binary property - OutlookSpy will parse it and display in the "Symb" edit box.

Comment: I've tried using OutlookSpy to open a changed occurrence as an IMessage. Tried manually updating "AppointmentStartWhole", "ClipStart", "CommonStart", "PR_START_DATE" to half an hour later than the original time. Saved the changes but did not see any change in Outlook. Restarted Outlook and all values were reverted back and no changes to the occurrence either. I found that this doesn't happen on all computers I've tested, it has happened on 3 out of 10 so could be an Outlook issue. Tried performing a full repair on one of them but did not help though.

Comment: Don't try to update the changed instance directly. The right exception data must be in the recurrence blob on the master appointment. Do you see it?

Comment: So instead of updating the changed occurrence, I should get the corresponding exception, change the exception data then call `Save` on the mater appointment? Because there's no `Save` method for neither the recurrence pattern nor the exception.

Comment: RDOAppointmentItem.Save on the instance of the recurring appointment should be enough - it will save the master appointment as well.